# How to replace pattern range using awk or sed

Tags: perl, awk, replace, sed

Some people format their JSON files where all the main data elements are inside an array. I want to promote the array elements to be json objects.

In other words ... I want to take any generic text file like this:

> {"foods":[{"fgid":"vf","fgcat_id":"1","srvg_sz":"125 mL, ½ cup, 6 spears","food":"Asparagus"},{"fgid":"vf","fgcat_id":"1","srvg_sz":"125 mL, ½ cup","food":"Beans, green"},{"fgid":"vf","fgcat_id":"1","srvg_sz":"125 mL, ½ cup cooked","food":"Bok choy/Chinese cabbage (Choi sum)"},{"fgid":"vf","fgcat_id":"1","srvg_sz":"125 mL, ½ cup","food":"Broccoli"},{"fgid":"vf","fgcat_id":"1","srvg_sz":"125 mL, ½ cup, 4 sprouts","food":"Brussels sprouts"},{"fgid":"vf","fgcat_id":"2","srvg_sz":"125 mL, ½ cup, 1 large","food":"Carrots"}]}

and find replace the range of text from the **first "{"** to the **first "["** and just replace it with "{{", and (in a separate command?) at the end replace the "]" so that it looks like this:

> {{"fgid":"vf","fgcat_id":"1","srvg_sz":"125 mL, ½ cup, 6 spears","food":"Asparagus"},{"fgid":"vf","fgcat_id":"1","srvg_sz":"125 mL, ½ cup","food":"Beans, green"},{"fgid":"vf","fgcat_id":"1","srvg_sz":"125 mL, ½ cup cooked","food":"Bok choy/Chinese cabbage (Choi sum)"},{"fgid":"vf","fgcat_id":"1","srvg_sz":"125 mL, ½ cup","food":"Broccoli"},{"fgid":"vf","fgcat_id":"1","srvg_sz":"125 mL, ½ cup, 4 sprouts","food":"Brussels sprouts"},{"fgid":"vf","fgcat_id":"2","srvg_sz":"125 mL, ½ cup, 1 large","food":"Carrots"}}

But I would like this to be for any similar file so I don't know the length of the "foods" text (or sometimes there are other elements before the array that I also want to wipe out before the first "[" starts). This would help me deal with Open Data from the Canadian government as all the JSON is in one object in an array. Thank you. I would be happy to use either sed or awk.

Comment: if they are all line by line, try `sed 's/^[^[]*\[/{/; s/\]}$/}/' file`

Comment: Is that latter valid JSON? Even so though - why not just use a JSON parser?

Comment: @Sobrique I just want to take out of array so if I import into mongo or rethink they get object ids

Comment: @Sundeep YES! thank you

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do the trick I think:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $json_str =
  '{"foods":[{"fgid":"vf","fgcat_id":"1","srvg_sz":"125 mL, ½ cup, 6 spears","food":"Asparagus"},{"fgid":"vf","fgcat_id":"1","srvg_sz":"125 mL, ½ cup","food":"Beans, green"},{"fgid":"vf","fgcat_id":"1","srvg_sz":"125 mL, ½ cup cooked","food":"Bok choy/Chinese cabbage (Choi sum)"},{"fgid":"vf","fgcat_id":"1","srvg_sz":"125 mL, ½ cup","food":"Broccoli"},{"fgid":"vf","fgcat_id":"1","srvg_sz":"125 mL, ½ cup, 4 sprouts","food":"Brussels sprouts"},{"fgid":"vf","fgcat_id":"2","srvg_sz":"125 mL, ½ cup, 1 large","food":"Carrots"}]}';

my $json_obj = from_json($json_str);
print Dumper \$json_obj;
my $json_arr = $json_obj -> {foods}; 
print to_json ( $json_arr, { pretty => 1 } );
```

I'm actually fairly sure your second example isn't actually valid JSON, as you can't do a 'sort of array' without using `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
sed -e '1s/{/{{/' -e '$s/\(.*\)]/\1/'
```

Below is the explanation:
-e is used to use multiple sed operation 
1s is to select first line
$s is to select last line
(.*)]/\1is to replace last occurrence of [.

Comment: "unterminated substitute pattern". I am using OSX if that matters.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.